# How to spell-check strings in my source code

Tags: asp.net, spell-checking

As I am such a lazy programmer, my code is riddled with strings and I don't use resource files like I should. I like to think I'm a good speller, but I have made mistakes...

```
MessageToUser = "Please clikc on teh button"  
DisplayPopup(MessageToUser)
```

I use Visual Web Developer to write VB.net and C#, but would also like to check Classic ASPs, Javascript files and even HTML. Is there a free tool to spell check my entire project (or every file in a directory)?

I've spotted [Softario](http://www.softario.com/scsc.html) (a bit old?), [BatchSpellChecker](http://www.batchspellchecker.com/) (doesn't mention .net) and [this VSIX](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce) (only for Visual Studio) but would like some reccomendations before I install something unknown. There may be a better tool?

(This question is not to be confused with the act of spellchecking a user's input into my program. It is words within the source code I wish to check.)

Comment: To be fair, "clikc" and "teh" are more likely typos than spelling errors. I doubt you thought consciously: _How do I spell click?...C.L.I.K.C_.

Comment: I have this firm belief that I read all the words I type, over again, and always spot mistaks. I doubt I'm as good as I think I am really...

Comment: I know I always catch every mistak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a visual studio extension called Spell Checker. Search for it in NuGet.

[Spell Checker Extension Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce/)

This was recommend by [Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/) in an Entity Framework Pluralsight tutorial.

Comment: Yes, and it doesnt work with VWD...at least not the Express version! I think I'd prefer a tool outside the IDE in some ways.

Comment: Hmm, start using visual studio, it is way better! Using a tool outside the IDE sounds like a ball ache to go back and correct spelling.